# Float GLUT window on top without titlebar on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, glut

I'm creating a simple commandline applicatiation that starts a GLUT window.
I need that GLUT window to be always on top and remove the titlebar.
Basically GLUT does not provide anything for this so i'm looking into other options. On Windows i would do something like:

```
glutCreateWindow( "dpd" ); //create window with glut
HWND hwnd = FindWindow( "GLUT", "dpd" ); 
SetWindowPos( hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SWP_NOREPOSITION | SWP_NOSIZE ); //set the window always-on-top
```

But how can i do such a thing on OSX? (C++)

I already use some Carbon code to remove the menubar, but the titlebar is still visible:

```
SetSystemUIMode(kUIModeAllHidden,KWindowNoTitleBarAttribute);
```

i'm new to OSX development and out of ideas..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out that there is now way to make changes / ajustments to a glut window. So i finaly created a workaround: i start glut on one thread, on an other thread i created a fullscreen window with a transparent background and created a dynamic backgroundimage (png) with a viewport with just the size of the GLUT window without the titlebar. Sound kind a ugly but hey, it works, the client does get the result they want within budget :)

If you think there is a better solution for this without creating a manual openGL implementation please let me know!